# What kind of semi-open file is better for your rook?

Tags: rooks

What kind of semi-open file is better for your rook?

One where your pawn is on it, or one where the opponents pawn is on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally when you read/hear something like "to put the rook on a semi-open file" it means a file where the opponent's pawn is on. The reasoning behind this is just *piece activity*, i.e. to maximize the available squares for the rook and also to attack something (the opponent's pawn on that file).

The only time where it makes sense (on general principles) to put a rook on a semi-open file where your own pawn is on, is if you want to support a passed pawn, typically with the rook from behind the pawn. However this situation would not be referred to as "putting the rook on a semi-open file".

PS: Of course there are situations (like the latter example above), where it could make sense to put the rook on a semi open file where your own pawn is located. However I understood your question as asking about the **general principle** that *rooks are supposed to be good on semi-open files*. In that  case it would always be the semi-open file with your opponent's pawn.